# Access Denied Issue Windows ( This is no longer location )

Tags: windows-10, permission-denied

I am getting  Access denied and This is no longer location issue in Windows 10 ,this i am getting for My documents , Pictures ,Videos and Music folder only.
any one help me to resolve the issue

[image]

Comment: Microsoft probably migrated your documents to OneDrive. Check in the OneDrive folder in your user folder.

Comment: Issue is its not allowing me to Delete or Create any new Document and mine is local user